# Webpack / Babel Error: Module build failed: (SystemJS) ENOENT: "object-assign"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, postcss

When I'm magrate webpack from v1 to v3, I meet the ERROR:

> ERROR in ./index.js
>   Module build failed: (SystemJS) ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/zhangcong/Desktop/g/mi-insight-web/object-assign'
>       Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/zhangcong/Desktop/g/mi-insight-web/object-assign'
>       Error loading /Users/zhangcong/Desktop/g/mi-insight-web/object-assign as "object-assign" from /Users/zhangcong/Desktop/g/mi-insight-web/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js

This is the migrate guide I followed: [see](https://javascriptplayground.com/moving-to-webpack-2/)

I'm trying to rename `modulesDirectories` as `modules`, but failed.

Something I've done:

```
-root: PATH.SOURCE_PATH,
-modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
-extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
+modules: ['node_modules'],
+extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
```

and I migrate the `postcss` and removed the `OccurenceOrderPlugin`.

I've tried using `path.resolve()`, and I can't figure out why `modules` failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by:

```
npm install postcss-import@8.0.2 --save-dev
```

see: [babel-loader#242](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/242)